# In C++, can we create a class for each integer?

Tags: c++, class, generics, constants, modular-arithmetic

I need to create a class `NumberModuloN`. For each positive integer `N`, there should be a distinct class. What is the most **elegant** way to do this?

Here are some more details: The data consists of a single integer in the range `0` to `N-1`. It can be modified using some public operator overloading methods like `+`, `*`, `-`, `++`, etc.

The idea is that, for example, an object of `numberModulo100` has no business with any object of `numberModulo99`. Adding, subtracting, multiplying them won't make sense.

One thing I came up with was to use a constant variable for `N` that gets initialised in the constructor. Here is a reference to constant variables https://stackoverflow.com/a/18775482/15360444. But the problem is that, now, every binary operator method would have to check if the `N`s of the two operands match before proceeding. It is not very elegant.

I need something similar to a C++ template which gives a different class for each data type. I just need a different class for each positive integer.

Comment: Hi, this is pretty good question, yet matters of elegancy are inherently opinion-based

Comment: See also [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use non-type parameter in template, so, something like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct NumberModuloN
{
    /*..*/
};
```

Comment: Aside: You can also specialise this for certain values, e.g. `template <> struct NumberModuloN<0>;` (an incomplete type) to prevent use of mod 0

Comment: @Caleth: `static_assert(N != 0);` seems enough here (or `requires (N != 0)`). But in fact act as template with type parameters.

Comment: It works. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!